# javascript objects only alerts first option

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Hello I am messing with an object in Javascript. Here is my object in a seperate .js file.

**json-webservice.js**

```
      //create object
function objdata(tool, product, details) {


    //create object properties
    this.tool = tool;
    this.product = product;
    this.details = details;


    //create object methods
    this.validate = function () {
        var error = 0;
        for (var prop in this) {

            if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if (prop != 'validate' || prop != 'submit') {
                    if (this[prop] == null || this[prop] == undefined || this[prop] == "") {
                        error += 1;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return error;
    }

    this.submit = function () {

        var error = this.validate();

        if (error > 0) {
            alert("errors: " + error);
        }
        else {
            alert(this.tool + " " + this.product + " " + this.details);
        }
    }

}


}
```

I include this script in the head of my page `index-main.html`.

Then document ready, and then initialize the new object and submit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var userdata = new objdata('5', 'Main Page', '9');
    userdata.submit();

});
```

My question is why does it only alert

```
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
5
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

and not

```
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
5 Main Page 9
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

like I think it should. Is my object correctly coded? I didn't have any javascript errors reported in IE.

The wierd part is I can copy the json-webservice.js file contents (the object above) and it works perfectly. It does not work as an external file though.

Comment: Consider using `console.log()` (and a real browser) instead of `alert()` for debugging.

Comment: You can probably reduce that `if` statement to just `if (!this.prop)`

Comment: Oh i would LOVE to! too bad this job all I have is IE7 ￢o(￣-￣ﾒ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this[prop]` rather than `this.prop`; the former looks for a property whose name is the string in `prop`, while the latter looks for a property whose name is literally "prop."

(I couldn't get it to reproduce the output you had. As written, it was just alerting "error", and the change above caused it to give the desired output.)

Comment: I changed some of the code. I think the logic is correct now. The issue I have is the same invalid output when the object is in an external .js file.

Comment: How are you calling it in the? Is the code in the external file exactly as it appears above?

Comment: I modified the question to clarify what exactly is in the object file. Any suggestions?